# Looping through in C#

Tags: c#

I need to find every single cordination in an X and Y KeyPairValue in C#, is there an easy way to do this?

I have the max X and max Y, and the min just starts at 1

```
int maxX = room.Model.MapSizeX;
int maxY = room.Model.MapSizeY;
```

Now, I just need to loop every possibility, but I don't really know how to do that, can someone help me with this? I think I just need to loop through everything in X and everything in Y but for every possibility between 1 and max for x and Y

Comment: What exactly are you looping through? Is it an array? A dictionary? A list?

Comment: Are you just asking how to make a *loop* in C#?  What have you tried?

Comment: Type on Google: loop in C# example

Comment: Obviously its an integer @BackDoorNoBaby I am asking the intelligence side of it

Comment: @LiamSavage what??

Comment: @LiamSavage "Now, I just need to loop every possibility".. what does that statement mean? You need to loop through every possible integer?

Comment: Every possible X and Y cordination until the max of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple with nested `for` loops. Iterate over the first range, and within that, iterate over the second range.

```
var minX = 1;
var minY = 1;
var maxX = 99;
var maxY = 99;

for (var currentX = minX; currentX <= maxX; ++currentX)
{
    for (var currentY = minY; currentY <= maxY; ++currentY)
    {
        // do something with each X,Y combination
    }
}
```